# Docker + Windows + Prometheus : How/Where to supply the configuration files

Tags: windows, docker, yaml, config, prometheus

I'm trying to pass in my own prometheus.yml file. I'm new to docker and the examples I'm finding are all on Linux systems and I'm on windows. How/where is the best way to supply my own yaml file? The command below fails to start the docker container.

```
docker run -d -p 9090:9090 -v c:\Docker\prometheus.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml --name=prometheus prom/prometheus -config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml -storage.local.path=/prometheus -storage.local.memory-chunks=10000
```

When I do try and run this command, Docker prompts me if I want to share my C: drive which I do but still no luck getting the container to run.

Here is what the docker logs say:

```
Error parsing commandline arguments: unknown short flag '-c'
prometheus: error: unknown short flag '-c'
```

So I removed the last few arguments that [Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-prometheus-using-docker-on-ubuntu-14-04) had in their example and the container now runs.

*`-storage.local.path=/prometheus -storage.local.memory-chunks=10000`*

So now my question is, do I need to have those configurations specified and if I do, what is the syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Was able to make it work in windows env.

For running prometheus with docker in the same network:

Check this: https://docs.docker.com/config/thirdparty/prometheus/

Steps:

- List item

  - Click the Docker icon in the toolbar, select Preferences, then select Daemon. Click Advanced.
    "metrics-addr" : "127.0.0.1:9323", "experimental" : true
  - restart docker
  - create C:\tmp\prometheus.yml [As per your choice]
  - under targets --> targets: ['docker.for.win.localhost:8001']
  - docker run --name container-name --network=network-name --mount type=bind,source=C:/tmp/prometheus.yml,destination=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml --publish published=9090,target=9090,protocol=tcp prom/prometheus
  - URL: localhost:9090

Hope this helps.
Have created a sample working project: https://github.com/mayank1989gupta/GradleAutoDeploy
You can find more details related to the same.

Answer (score 2):

That tutorial from DO is outdated. Basically, tho related things [were changed](https://prometheus.io/blog/2017/06/21/prometheus-20-alpha3-new-rule-format/) in Prometheus since v2.0:

- new CLI options format: double dash for long options, like `--config.file`
- options `storage.local.*` (and some others) were removed

Correct command would be:

`docker run -d -p 9090:9090 -v c:\Docker\prometheus.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml --name=prometheus prom/prometheus --config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml`

Answer (score 1):

Change the command to:

`docker run -d -p 9090:9090 -v c:\Docker\prometheus.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml --name=prometheus prom/prometheus --config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml -storage.local.path=/prometheus -storage.local.memory-chunks=10000`

You just need to make `-config` to `--config` by adding a `-` before `-config`.

It worked for me.